# WPF databinding not working despite the target datacontext bound to the correct source memory address

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

The scenario is very simple here. I'm trying to bind a textbox to a property of a class at runtime:

```
tb.displayValue.DataContext = p.GetValue(currentNode, null);
```

xaml for the textbox:

```
<TextBox Name="displayValue" Grid.Column="1" 
                 Style="{StaticResource propertyTextBoxStyle}" 
                 Text="{Binding Path=DataContext, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                        Mode=TwoWay, 
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
 </TextBox>
```

When the application starts, the textbox does get populated with the correct information so the source to target binding is working fine. However, when I try and edit a value in the textbox and then switch focus, the changes are not reflected in the actual data structure. The value would stay on the UI, but as soon as I try to reload the UI from the data structure again it defaults back to the original value.

I suspect the binding is not working correctly at first, but after checking the memory address of `tb.displayValue.DataContext` and comparing it to the actual memory address of the data structure it's an identical match.
`INotifyPropertyChanged` has been implemented and I have added the `OnPropertyChanged` call to every setter. After spending two days trying to debug this issue I think I'm really running out of options here so any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a debug converter to look at what your data context is?

Comment: Are you getting any binding errors or any other errors in the output window during debugging when you change the value in the textbox and switch focus?

Comment: What is that data structure you are talking about? Apparently your `p.GetValue` method returns just a string. How should data flow from target to source when there is no source property? You should have a binding source object with a string property, set the DataContext to the source object, and bind to the property. See the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN for how to start with WPF data binding. Besides that, there is nothing like "memory address" in C#.

Comment: @Versatile Tried that and the correct data is being passed

Comment: @Zack I've tried to set PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel to high in the text binding for the textbox and when I try to change the value I'm getting the [following warnings](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/zhb94430/f5d244b01983937fa1bc06a045413242/raw/41e3d356b37a125940f746700b3ba4ed7ccfe53a/new_gist_file_0). It doesn't look like there's anything out of place but I could very well be wrong

Comment: @Clemens The data structure is just a list of a custom class to store the data being parsed from an XML file. Can you elaborate a bit more on the source property part? I'm still very new to databinding in WPF. `p.GetValue` doesn't necessarily return a string value. It returns whatever object the current `PropertyIfo p` represents. It could be a `double` or `string` in this case. I'm only mentioning memory address because when I go into the memory window in the debugger I was able to locate the exact memory address for both the source and the `DataContext` bound to the target.

Comment: Read the Data Binding Overview article. It is essential for a basic understanding. The binding expression that you currently have makes no sense. It is equivalent to `{Binding Path=., UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`, i.e. there is no source property that could be set by the target-to-source direction of a two-way binding.

Comment: Listen to the dataContext_changed event and let us know how data context is changing. Look at the e.NewValue property when you enter into the edit mode or when the focus is lost from the control.

Comment: @Clemens This is where I'm having a little bit hard time understanding. The binding expression is the first thing I thought of when I tried to debug this issue. However I'm having a hard time understanding why the binding expression I have right now could work for the one way binding (given the UI is displaying the value correctly) but not for two way binding. If the binding expression is void shouldn't the binding stops working both ways?

Comment: Where/why exactly are you setting the `DataContext` on the TextBox? Usually you have a `ViewModel` which you create and set as the `DataContext` for your `Window`, and you bind to public properties on that `ViewModel` class. Have you at least been able to get that far before, so you can see how it is supposed to work, before attempting to do it how you are doing it now? Is `p` in this case a `DependencyProperty` in your `Window` code-behind?

Comment: @Zack You are right. The problem is coming from setting the `DataContext`. I ended up getting rid of the line that sets the `DataContext` and created the binding from scratch in my view model. The reason I was trying to set the `DataContext` on the `TextBox` was because I was trying to populate the `TextBox` with data available only at runtime but setting the binding from scratch is a much better solution in this case. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest two-way binding works this way: you set the `DataContext` on your `Window` to a new instance of your `MainWindowViewModel` class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and you set the binding path on your `TextBox` to the name of the public property on your `ViewModel` you want to bind to.

I'm trying to show how you need a public property with a get and set to bind to, and how to properly set the `DataContext` for your window so that all of the controls within it are able to bind to the public properties available on it.

I've never heard of setting the `DataContext` of a `TextBox` directly to the return value from a method before, and it just seems wrong, so maybe you are not going about it the right way, and hopefully this helps you see how it can work.

### MainWindow.cs

```
<Window x:Class="DemoWPFApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DemoWPFApp1.ViewModels"
        Height="300" Width="460" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <TextBox Name="displayValue" Text="{Binding Path=BoundProperty,
         Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    </TextBox>
</Window>
```

### MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
namespace DemoWPFApp1.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string m_boundProperty;
        public string BoundProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return m_boundProperty;
            }
            set
            {
                m_boundProperty = value; OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            BoundProperty = "Some value.";
        }
    }
}
```

### BaseViewModel.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace DemoWPFApp1.ViewModels
{
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
        {
            var e = PropertyChanged;
            if (e != null && propName != null)
            {
                e.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```